# Triggering 'focusout' (or similar) for parent elements

Tags: javascript, forms, focusout

I have an (obviously simplified) form structure like so:

```
 <form class = 'crud'>
  <div class = 'record' id='record_0'>
    <input id='testa_0' name='testa' class = 'crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_0' name='testb' class = 'crud-control'>
  </div>
  <div class = 'record' id='record_1'>
    <input id='testa_1' name='testa' class = 'crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_1' name='testb' class = 'crud-control'>
  </div>
  <div class = 'record' id='record_2'>
    <input id='testa_2' name='testa' class = 'crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_2' name='testb' class = 'crud-control'>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would like to trigger an event (for data submission), when the user moves from an input element within one record to another record (actually clicks/moves outside the current record), but **not** when the user moves from one input to another input that's a descendant of the same `div.record`.

I have tried to attach a `.focusout()` event handler to `div.record`, but that fires also, when moving from input to another input 'within' the same record -- I suppose that's normal behavior due to bubbling.

Any suggestions, on how to proceed?

Comment: if user moves focus from `record_0` to `record_1` and form gets submitted, `record_2` fiels will be empty. if that's inteded?

Comment: @Vaibhav ... if user moves from `record_x`' to 'record_y' or actually anywhere "outside" of `record_x`, form get's submitted ... nothing special happening to `record_z` -- question is, how do I capture the move outside `record_x` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `blur` events to the input fields like this:

```js
const testa_0 = document.getElementById('testa_0');
testa_0?.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  //check if the new target is in the same parent or not
  if (event.target.parentElement != event.relatedTarget?.parentElement) {
    //parent is changed
    //do whatever you like to do
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I woould use both `focus` and `blur` events.
On `blur`, store the parent element in a variable.
On `focus`, if the parent is not the same, do something.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".record input")
let parent

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
    parent = e.target.closest(".record")
  })

  input.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    if (parent && e.target.closest(".record") !== parent) {
      console.log("Do something here.")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form class='crud'>
  <div class='record' id='record_0'>
    <input id='testa_0' name='testa' class='crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_0' name='testb' class='crud-control'>
  </div>
  <div class='record' id='record_1'>
    <input id='testa_1' name='testa' class='crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_1' name='testb' class='crud-control'>
  </div>
  <div class='record' id='record_2'>
    <input id='testa_2' name='testa' class='crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_2' name='testb' class='crud-control'>
  </div>
</form>
```